# Apt trying to fetch versions not available in archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main

Tags: apt, 20.04, official-repositories

I keep getting failed to fetch errors from the primary Ubuntu repository for *gcc* and related. I have run `sudo apt update --fix-missing` and `sudo apt upgrade` and the errors remain the same.

Looking at http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-9/ I can verify that a) the server is responding properly and b) there are archives there to fetch, just not the versions that apt is looking for.

Why is apt looking for different versions? How do I reset or rebuild whatever list apt is using for version numbers?

```
Err:6 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libc-dev-bin amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Ign:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.4.0-100.113
Err:8 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libc6-dev amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:9 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libc6-dbg amd64 2.31-0ubuntu9.2
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:1 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gcc-9-base amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:2 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 cpp-9 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libasan5 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 libgcc-9-dev amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:5 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 gcc-9 amd64 9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:7 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates/main amd64 linux-libc-dev amd64 5.4.0-100.113
  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Unable to correct missing packages.
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-9/gcc-9-base_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
E: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main/g/gcc-9/cpp-9_9.3.0-17ubuntu1~20.04_amd64.deb  404  Not Found [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
```

Comment: Try removing (or moving away) everything from /var/lib/apt/lists/, then do sudo apt update, then sudo apt upgrade.

Comment: thanks @nsilent22 that seemed to knock something loose, but now I get package not installed, "you may held broken packages". Console log at https://gist.github.com/maphew/41c186f679050ac59cdc88d3143443a0

Comment: 1. Is your clock set correctly? 
2. Have you installed some 'non native' packages lately? If yes - remove them.

Comment: @nsilent22: Time was set correctly to local time but timezone was etc/UTC. I set the timezone and set the time again, and then apt update and upgrade both worked, and then `apt install gcc` worked. The gcc version installed was `9.4.0-1` whereas yesterday the error ones were `9.3.0-17`. Open question whether time settings change was the trick or if something changed upstream betweern yesterday and today. Either way, thank you! Add as answer so I can mark it solved. :)

Comment: I'm glad I could help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. Try removing content of `/var/lib/apt/lists/` - may contain some broken/outdated package lists. After `sudo apt update` should be as good as new.
2. Messages about release file being "not valid yet" may be because of a clock skew. Make sure your clock is set correctly.
3. When you get messages about conflicting packages try to remove them and reinstall afterwards.