# Ubuntu 20.04.4 LTS update Connection failed error

Tags: apt, 20.04, updates

The `sudo apt-get update` or  `sudo apt install python3-pip` leads to errors.

I pinged google and the IP that was given for Ubuntu update and all went over fine

[update error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KdUfo.png)

```
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Err:2 http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-security InRelease          
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
Err:3 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-updates InRelease            
  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
Err:4 http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu focal-backports InRelease
  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
Reading package lists... Done
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-updates/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-backports/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 185.125.190.39 80]
W: Failed to fetch http://security.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/dists/focal-security/InRelease  Connection failed [IP: 91.189.91.38 80]
W: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

[ping the same update IP](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xX4EC.png)

[Installing packages error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Utu2l.png)

Comment: What kept you from just copy/paste the output? Did you retry later?

Comment: I added the output error. Yes I have tried later but same error

Comment: Even Tried nameserver 8.8.8.8 and still not working

Comment: Nameserver is not your problem - your log shows the IP. Did you [investigate](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402336/apt-trying-to-fetch-versions-not-available-in-archive-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-pool-mai) ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Apt trying to fetch versions not available in archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/pool/main](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1402336/apt-trying-to-fetch-versions-not-available-in-archive-ubuntu-com-ubuntu-pool-mai)